# Facebook Open Graph Refresh

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've used the debugger - > https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ which shows the correct image and tag line for my domain when showing the initial existing scrape information.  It also shows correctly when I fetch new scrape information.

However, when I attempt to share the url from any timeline, it shows an old image and old tag line.  I've tried variants of ?fbrefresh=timestamp, ?fbrefresh=1 etc.  I've even appended a timestamp to the og:image url.

Additionally, the dev tool complains about the og:image saying it could not be downloaded referencing the url (which is valid and pulls up the image in any browser) and again is shown correctly at the bottom of the dev tool page, or it is too small referencing 200px x 200px minimum, however the image is 540px x 300px! And goes on to say its going to use the older cahced image instead which IS what shows when I attempt to share the url.

Furthermore it also complains about "Inferred Property" for og:url, og:title, og:description and og:image even though when I view the scrape the tags are clearly there each with their own meta html element and explicitly providing a correct "content" attribute.  I have verified the og:url, fetched url, cannonical url and cached url are all the same.

I've also confirmed trying the url w/ and w/out http, https, and www combinations make no difference when sharing the url.  The only difference that clearly shows a problem is the amount of likes is different even though I would expect fb to know w/ and w/out www. is the same domain since they share the same og information.  As a matter of fact, w/out the www redirects to www anyway.

It seems to me as if the fb og system has some serious bugs but no way to contact the dev team or report the problem that I can easily find.

I'm posting here first to see if I'm overlooking some crucial part that the stack community can help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that everything started working properly once I forced a new scrape using the dev tool against all possible domain variants.  I had thought I had tried this already but I guess I did not.  Such as:

"mywebsite.com"

"www.mywebsite.com"

"http://mywebsite.com"

"http://www.mywebsite.com"

"https://mywebsite.com"

"https://www.mywebsite.com"

Answer (score -1):

Implement all open graph tags, using the main URL only and scrape new information using the debuger. The posts sharing that URL or ANY variants will have the image, description, etc from the URL you specificate on Open Graph og.url tag. All the variants points to the same URL. There is the only place the og information is ;)

Comment: Yes this was how it was done yet it did not work until I used the debugger to rescrape all root and www domain possibilities